# How to do custom auth::attempt message on laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I need help so when he login there is different errors for example this is my code, stil don't know how to return different errors.

```
public function postLogin() 
    {
        $user = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password'),
            'active'    => 1
            );


        if (Auth::attempt($user, (Input::get('remember') == 'on') ? true : false)) {
            return Redirect::route('home');
        }

        // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
        return Redirect::route('login')
            ->with('flash', ['message'  =>  '<strong>Error!</strong> Account is not registered.', 
                'type'      =>  'danger']);
    }
```

my question is how to add these two custom redirect

if the user have correct username/password but `active = 0`, it will return

```
return Redirect::route('login')
            ->with('flash', ['message'  =>  '<strong>Error!</strong> Account is not verified.', 
                'type'      =>  'danger']);
```

and if the user have wrong username/password, it will return like this

```
return Redirect::route('login')
                ->with('flash', ['message'  =>  '<strong>Error!</strong> Wrong password.', 
                    'type'      =>  'danger']);
```

**EDIT1**

```
public function postLogin() 
    {
        $user = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password'),
            );


        if(Auth::attempt($user, (Input::get('remember') == 'on') ? true : false)) {
            if(Auth::user()->active == 1) {
                if(Auth::user()->isBanned == 0 ) {
                    return Redirect::route('home');
                }

                Auth::logout();
                $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Your account was banned for misconduct.';
            }

            Auth::logout();
            $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Account is not verified.';
        } else {
            $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Wrong password.';
        }

        // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
        return Redirect::route('login')
            ->with('flash', ['message'  =>  $message, 
                'type'      =>  'danger']);
    }
```

**EDIT2**

MY ANSWER

```
public function postLogin() 
{
    $user = array(
        'email'     => Input::get('email'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password'),
        );


    if(Auth::attempt($user, (Input::get('remember') == 'on') ? true : false)) {
        if(Auth::user()->active == 1 && Auth::user()->isBanned == 0) {
            return Redirect::route('home');
        }

        if(Auth::user()->active == 0) {
            $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Account is not verified.';
        } else if (Auth::user()->isBanned == 1) {
            $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Your account was banned for misconduct.';
        }

        Auth::logout();

    } else {
        $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Wrong password.';
    }

    // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
    return Redirect::route('login')
        ->with('flash', ['message'  =>  $message, 
            'type'      =>  'danger']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
public function postLogin() 
{
    $user = array(
        'email'     => Input::get('email'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password')
    );


    if (Auth::attempt($user, Input::has('remember'))) {

        if (Auth::user()->active == 1 && Auth::user()->isBanned != 0) {
            return Redirect::route('home');
        }

        $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Account is not verified.';

        if (Auth::user()->isBanned == 0) {
            $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Your account was banned for misconduct.';
        }

        Auth::logout();

    } else {
        $message = '<strong>Error!</strong> Wrong password.';
    }

    return Redirect::route('login')
        ->with('flash', [
            'message'  =>  $message, 
            'type'      =>  'danger'
        ]);

}
```

Comment: he can still login though,

Comment: cause I have `Route::filter('guest', function()
{
 if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::route('home');
});`  on `filter.php`

Comment: See the updated answer. Forgot to logout after the activation check.

Comment: not working, cause when he got `active=1` he can't read anymore on the bottom if he's ban or not

Comment: thanks... my answer is already done, look at my updated question, need the `Auth::logout();` below so when we check `if(Auth::user()->active == 0)` there is no error, or else he doens't know who's the user when it's already logouted

Comment: Yes. `Auth::logout();` should come after the banned check. :)